# Write array values to Range

Tags: excel, vba

Code to add values to array, then copy those values to a range.

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim myarray(1 To 10, 1 To 5) As Variant

For r = 1 To 10
For c = 1 To 5
myarray(r, c) = 1
Next c
Next r

Range("A1:E10").Value = myarray
```

So, if I only wanted to copy the last five rows of array data to Range("A1:E5"), how would I do that? I know how to achieve this via looping, but I want to do it without looping.

Range("A1:E5").Value = ???

Comment: fastest way is to create another array of the size you want, then loop and load that array from the the desired part of the original array.  Then bulk load from the new array.  Any other method of splicing that does not require a loop will be slower.  This has been tested and proved many times over.  I would create a Function that takes the original array and desired number of rows and does the looping and returns the desired array.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can just use `Dim myArray() AS Variant: myArray = Range("A1:E10")`, to create & fill the array without needing loops.  (Although, IIRC, this will be 0-Indexed, so `(0 to 9, 0 to 4)`, not `(1 to 10, 1 to 5)`)

Comment: @Chronocidal - no, it will be one-based.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the correction, it's been a while since I used that trick, and I don't have Excel on this machine to verify

Comment: @Scott Craner, thanks for the reply. If you have the time and inclination, could you help me out with the code for the Function? I simply wouldn't know how to write that.

Comment: @Chronocidal The array values would not be coming from worksheet cells, which is what is what it looks like your Dim statement does.